# Firebase Storage REST API - Invalid Credentials (using Email/Password auth)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get Firebase to let me download a test file I have uploaded. I'm using the REST API and my rules are pretty much default:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
   }
}
```

I have a email/password user created and have "Email/Password" enabled as a "Sign-In Method".

The process I'm following is:

1. Call https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit to get a refresh_token
2. Pass refresh_token to https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token for access_token
3. Add access_token to "Authorization" header (prefixed with "Bearer ") on call to [https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/{bucket}/o/{filename}](https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/%7Bbucket%7D/o/%7Bfilename%7D)

Steps 1 and 2 work perfect, and the response to Step 2 includes the userID of the user I'm trying to authenticate with. However, Step 3 is returning "Invalid Credentials" as HTML.

Pulling my hair out over this. Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT:**
I'm populating the bucket and object by straight string replacement.  I tested an http encoded string before posting this and I'm still getting the same response.  My url:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/carnage-dynamic-asset-bundles.appspot.com/o/Remember_Bundle_1_v1.zip?key={API_Key}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you are populating bucket and object in the URL.  There are specific instructions: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/

Comment: And are you passing the refresh token instead of the oauth2 id token? I don't think the refresh token is going to work for you.  You use that when the id token expires after an hour.

Comment: When I pass the id token from IdentityToolkit to  TokenService the response states "INVALID_ID_TOKEN", passing refresh_token was only way I could get a response.

Comment: I did notice that in response from TokenService, access_token and id_token are identical.